# Why `config.headers` in interceptor is possibly undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, axios, interceptor

I'm new in nodejs so it gets hard to me to fix some problems, thank you in advance.
So here is my `.../src/http/index.ts` file

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const API_URL = `http://localhost:5000/api`

const $api = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: API_URL
})

$api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization= `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    return config
})

export default $api
```

and `config.headers` in here is underlined and ts shows me that

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532
12 |
13 | $api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
14 |     config.headers.Authorization= `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
   |     ^
15 |     return config
16 | })
17 |
```

I've just thinking on it so long and can't get what the problem is

> AxiosRequestConfig.headers?: Record<string, string>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you that the way Axios defines its TypeScript types for its API, `config` may be `undefined` when your interceptor function is called. (And it [looks that way](https://tsplay.dev/w8AlAN) in the TypeScript playground as well.) The [interceptors documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) doesn't say anything either way, which seems odd.

If you're **sure** that the `config` parameter will never be `undefined`, you can include an assertion saying that:

```typescript
$api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    if (!config?.headers) {
        throw new Error(`Expected 'config' and 'config.headers' not to be undefined`);
    }
    config.headers.Authorization= `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
    return config;
});
```

If you're incorrect, that will result in a runtime error.

If you aren't sure, you could create the config if needed:

```typescript
$api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    if (!config) {
        config = {};
    }
    if (!config.headers) {
        config.headers = {};
    }
    config.headers.Authorization= `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
    return config;
});
```